# Handle views using Phoenix as a RESTful API app

Tags: rest, api, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having trouble understanding how to handle phoenix views properly.
Let's say that a client is calling "login_user" api.
My controller will handle the request, checking if user is enabled to access or not. As response, i need to send user's data to the caller.
Now, after controller's login logic, what's the proper way to respond?

1) fetch all data needed by the caller inside the controller:

```
user_data = function_that_fetch_user_data()

conn
|> put_resp_header("content-type", "application/json")
|> put_status(:ok)
|> send_resp(Status.code(:ok), user_data)
```

2) render the view

```
conn
|> put_resp_header("content-type", "application/json")
|> put_status(:ok)
|> render(login.json, user)
```

and fetch data inside it

```
defmodule CryptomonitorWeb.UserView do
  use MyAppWeb, :view

  def render("login.json", user) do
    token = generate_user_token(user.mail)
    %{
       token: token,
       email: user.mail,
       group: "operators"
     }
  end

end
```

Getting data and building my response directly in the controller is more clear and clean to me, but i want to know what's the "right" way to handle api responses. My app will usually just return json to the client and sometimes render some html page.

Answer (score 1):

Views are representation of a data you want to send to as a response. So first you need to have some data, second you have to present it in the way it have to be presented in some API or an HTML page.

You are definitely don't want to go into a database from a view, but if you don't go there, then the border is more subtle.

Still, `generate_user_token` looks like a data emitter, not like a data presenter. And who knows, maybe one day someone will change the function, so it'll hit a database to generate token.

To avoid related troubles, better to have data generators out of a view. Place them into controller, then send results to a view.

So, I'm voting for option 1.

Comment: But option one is not using view at all. It just fetch, organize and send data directly to the caller without passing through view

Comment: So it's about using `send_resp` vs `render`. I vote for `render` and using a view because it extends better when needed.